# Is there a way to select multiple cursors between different groups in VSCode?

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code, text-editor

In VS Code we can split the screen into different **groups**. Is there a way to select multiple cursors between these groups? This would be useful to do scrolling between different files, for example

Answer (score 1):

No, cursors can only be active in a single editor. I believe that https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/38893 tracks this feature request

Comment: Cool, I was about to create a issue for this. Sad that no body has answered to it, though. Thanks!